# Trouble with Jekyll and Blog hosting

Tags: github, jekyll

I was trying to create a blog using github + jekyll + mathjx. I am totally a novice to programming and computer jargon. It seems I messed up with fonts somewhere somehow. Now the usual formatting is lost. Could you please help me restore the fonts and page outline as we get at the beginning after installation.[image]

Comment: Looks like CSS is not loaded. Might be a typo in a path to a CSS file or forgot to actually add the file to git when pushing. "Could you please help me restore the fonts" - no, we can't, because we don't have your code. You're using git, so it should be as simple as reverting to last known good commit and retrying from there.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.